# expressjs res.send and backbone

Tags: backbone.js, express

This is probably a very obvious mistake but I don't understand what's going on:
Server side:

```
this.app.get('/ripple/dataapiV2/reports',function(req,res) {
    console.log("Send REPORTS!!");
    res.status(200).send("plouf");
});
```

Client side, simple backbone model:

```
var RippleAccountTransactionStats = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attr,issuer) {

        this.url= config.rippledataapi.account_transaction_stats.urlModel;  

    }

});
```

The url is the right one when I fetch "SEND REPORTS" is visible in server console.
But front side the backbone fetch error is triggered:

```
var model = new RippleAccountTransactionStat({id:account.id},account.address);
        var xhr = model.fetch({
            success: function(model,response) {
                console.log("responssseee",response);
                self.add(model);
            },
            error: function(res,err) {
                console.log("account_transaction_stats fetch error", err,res);
            }
        });
```

I know it's hard to guess with only that information but really I have no clue why it's not workign properly. If anyone has an hint/clue it would be awesome. thanks in advance.

Weird thing responseText receive the text "plouf" but it's in the error callback I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

backbone wants json

```
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(someobject));
```

and then success is triggered